# android design library 28.0.0 causes app to crash

Tags: android, crash, android-support-library

Including android design library to the dependencies causes app to crash.

Im launching this on Nexus S emulator with 25 API. All my libraries are of the same version, so I don't know what's the problem.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' //this one
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0' // For CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Might help if you put the console or terminal output to show the error that is happening during crash.

Comment: share logs only then we can figure out the crash

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your code to AndroidX, the new SDK dependency dir structure will help you avoid such problems now and in the future.

Comment: Ok it is a good tip, but it doesn't seam the reason of the issue.